# How to understand param-values in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

In the XML below,

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>moReceiver</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>hms.kite.samples.api.sms.MoSmsReceiver</servlet-class>

  <init-param>
    <param-name>smsReceiver</param-name>
    <param-value>com.devsapce.samples.sms.FeedbackListner</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```

What is implied by `com.devsapce.samples.sms.FeedbackListner`? If I copy this into my web.xml file how could I change this to adapt it to my application?

I do not have a folder named "devspace/samples/sms". I have stored files in "C:\Users\nser\workspace\cofeeshop".

Comment: Where did you get this code from?  Are you asking what to change it to or what it does?

Comment: The `<param-value>` will be read in `init` method of the servlet as a `String`. It's part of the implementation of the `init` method to give a proper use to this parameter.

Comment: this is from a tutorial on using a SMS api to make simple apps based on sms! I want to know how to change the line "<param-value>com.devsapce.samples.sms.FeedbackListner</param-value>" because I don't have a folder path like devspace/samples/sms ! Actually I dont know what that line means

Comment: It's the path of the class.  Similar to how you import classes into other classes.

Comment: is it alright then if I put ""cofeeshop.Feedbacklistner" instead of "com.devsapce.samples.sms.FeedbackListner" ?

Comment: If that is the path of your FeedbackListner, then yes.

Comment: Asked a more clear question